# Can this code be rewritten to be more pythonic?

Tags: python, optimization

I read in values from a file. I have a line that has this format
size = 'GG|0,WQ|3,EW|8,RE|23'
I want it to be a list of dictionary.
Right now I use this code which works perfect but it seems like there has to be a cleaner way to do it.

```
>>> size = 'GG|0,WQ|3,EW|8,RE|23'
>>> a = [{i.split('|')[0]:i.split('|')[1]} for i in size.split(',')]
>>> a
[{'GG': '0'}, {'WQ': '3'}, {'EW': '8'}, {'RE': '23'}]
>>>
```

Comment: Can you change the format of the file?

Comment: Like is this for a class, can that formate be easily changed?

Comment: Why is each in its own dict when they have unique keys?

Comment: @JeffreyHaines No I can't change the format I am getting the file this way

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the keys are unique to each row, but other rows have the same keys but with different associated values with it

Comment: So then the answer is "no reason at all".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Oh sorry I see what you meant. After this it is sent over to be processed and combined with other data. I am using a dict to hold the values. So thats why they all need their own dict instead of using one dict since the keys are unique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
size = 'GG|0,WQ|3,EW|8,RE|23'
elements = size.split(',')
a = [dict([x.split('|')]) for x in elements]
```

Comment: Like it, it removes the duplication of split and the use of hard indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use python regex... You can take this further obviously

```
import re
size = 'GG|0,WQ|3,EW|8,RE|23'
pattern = re.compile('[A-Z][A-Z][|][0-9]+')
my_list = re.findall(pattern, size)
my_dic = [dict([item.split('|')]) for item in my_list]
```